# Using OR in conditional fields

Tags: 7, entities

I have several select fields in content type, which is more like Q/A & most of the answers are YES/NO. It's like tree flow, all question are dependent upon answer of previous question.

I am using [condition fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) & [field conditional state](https://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state) module for this purpose. OR can be implemented by help of FIELD CONDITIONAL STATE as module description says --

```
Module supports AND/OR functionality for control fields which means:

    AND - all choices must be selected to control the filed
      (example: field A will be visible when in field B option 1 and option 2 is selected)
    OR - any choice will control field
      (example: field A will be visible when in field B option 1 or option 2 is selected).
```

But I have some fields(e.g. Field C) which should be appear on selection of YES of Field A or NO of Field B.

Is it possible to achieve it by this module or some other way by any contributed module. I am not looking for making my own form by FORM API as I have around 60 question in content type & it will become so messy to manage in code.

**Edited --**

I have searched & got option such as using OR in conditional field in this manner-

```
field_atleast_50_capital is visible when field_property_deriving has value "No".
OR
field_atleast_50_capital is visible when field_arrangements_90_subsidiary has value "Yes".
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

just an observation from looking at the module documentation:

there is a note under *interaction with other dependencies* on the *Edit dependency* page which says this:

**When this dependent has more than one dependee, how should this condition be evaluated against the others?**
Note that sets will be grouped this way: `ANDs` AND `ORs` AND `XORs`

with a selection for `AND`, `OR` and `XOR`

This would indicate that you

- define your dependency of field C on A,
- define your dependency of field C on B
- and select *OR* as your interaction with other dependencies

Comment: The OR option which you are talking about has been tested by me, which comes from condition field module at standalone configuration of the module, which I accessed from module page itself. I put one condition & check it to interact with other condition as OR and added one more condition, but it didn't work..

Comment: I have the same problem, I used conditional fields with "OR" and it didn't work as expected. I had to set values manually in one of the field but it doesn't even work in another form I am making.